# Changing Property in code behind does not update view

Tags: xamarin.forms, data-binding

When I change my property which is a model object, The view does not update unless I reassign the binding context. I am not using mvvm, so no view model.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    
    private MySource _myCurrentSource = new MySource("yolor");

    public MySource MyCurrentSource {
        get { return _myCurrentSource; }
        set  {_myCurrentSource = value; } 
    }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyCurrentSource = _myCurrentSource;
        MainStack.BindingContext = MyCurrentSource;
        label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("SourceString"));
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyCurrentSource = new MySource("new string");
        //property changed
        MainStack.BindingContext = MyCurrentSource;
    }
}
```

**I want to get rid of :** `MainStack.BindingContext = MyCurrentSource;`

This is what my xaml looks like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="DataBindingPlayGround.MainPage">

    <StackLayout Padding="10, 0" x:Name="MainStack" HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Label x:Name="label" Text="TEXT" FontSize="48" />
        <Button Text="Change" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Model class:

```
    public class MySource
{
    public MySource(string str)
    {
        SourceString = str;
    }
    public string SourceString { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you need to use INotifyPropertyChanged.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm#interactive-mvvm or any of the dozens of existing questions on this topic

Answer (score 1):

Modify **MySource** class as follows to have a try:

```
public class MySource : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MySource(string str)
    {
        sourceString = str;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private string sourceString;

    public double SourceString 
    {
        set
        {
            if (sourceString != value)
            {
                sourceString = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SourceString");
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return sourceString;
        }
    }
}
```

=============================Update=================================

Although not understanding the logic of your application, if you want to make `MyCurrentSource` works. You will also need to use `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage ,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }    

    private MySource _myCurrentSource;
    
    public MySource MyCurrentSource
    {
        set
        {
            if (_myCurrentSource != value)
            {
                _myCurrentSource = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MyCurrentSource");
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return _myCurrentSource;
        }
    } 

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _myCurrentSource = new MySource("yolor");
        //MyCurrentSource = _myCurrentSource;
        MainStack.BindingContext = _myCurrentSource ;
        label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("SourceString"));
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _myCurrentSource = new MySource("new string");
        //property changed
        MainStack.BindingContext = _myCurrentSource;
    }
}
```

**Or** you can directly set new Model when **BindingContext**.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainStack.BindingContext = new MySource("yolor");
        label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("SourceString"));
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //property changed
        MainStack.BindingContext = new MySource("new string");
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the mentioned changes now if I do this `MyCurrentSource.SourceString = "string changed"` it works.
But what I wanted and that still does not happen is:
`MyCurrentSource= new MySource("new string")`
Note:  MyCurrentSource is a property in code-behind, and it is backed by:
`private MySource _myCurrentSource = new MySource("yolor");`

Comment: I am not interested in changing a property of my object, I want to assign a new object to my property in code behind, Practically I received two objects from a communication channel having many fields. And I need to update UI accordingly. So I want to assign those new objects to my two properties in code-behind. In UI two different stack layouts have these two properties as their binding context.

Comment: Because there are something wrong in `ContentPage`. You have not understanded my shared reply by using `INotifyPropertyChanged`. If you can use this for `MyCurrentSource`, it also will work.

Comment: This was helpful. Although it is not working in codebehind i.2 (Mainpage implementing the interface), But tried the same thing using a view model class and it works really good. I added the resulting code as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: @UmerMehmood Glad have solved it. Remember to mark the answer when you can.

Answer (score 0):

This is finally what worked for me, in case anyone has similar situation:
Source classes below:

```
    public class FirstSource
{
    public string sourceString;
    public string SourceString { get; set; }
    public int SourceOneProp2 { get; set; }


    public FirstSource(string str, int num)
    {
        SourceString = str;
        SourceOneProp2 = num;
    }
   
}
    public class SecondSource
{
    public string ExampleField { get; set; }
    public int SourceTwoProp2 { get; set; }

    public SecondSource(string exampleField, int num)
    {
        ExampleField = exampleField;
        SourceTwoProp2 = num;
    }
}
```

**ViewModel (Decided to use to make task easier)**

```
    class MainPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private FirstSource _sourceOne;
    private SecondSource _sourceTwo;

    public FirstSource SourceOne
    {
        get { return _sourceOne; } 
        set { SetValue(ref _sourceOne, value); }
    }

    public SecondSource SourceTwo
    {
        get { return _sourceTwo; }
        set { SetValue(ref _sourceTwo, value); }
    }

}
```

**Code Behind:**

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    int counter = 0;

    private MainPageViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return BindingContext as MainPageViewModel; }
        set { BindingContext = value; }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = new MainPageViewModel();
        ViewModel.SourceOne = new FirstSource("init1", 10);
        ViewModel.SourceTwo = new SecondSource("init2", 20);
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter += 1;
        ViewModel.SourceOne = new FirstSource("Changed1", 100+counter);
    }

    private void Button_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter += 1;
        ViewModel.SourceTwo = new SecondSource("Changed2", 200+counter);

    }
}
```

**XAML/UI**

```
    <StackLayout Padding="10, 0" x:Name="MainStack" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start">
    <Label x:Name="label" Text="{Binding Path=SourceOne.SourceString}" FontSize="48" />
    <Label Text="{Binding Path=SourceOne.SourceOneProp2}" />
    <Button Text="Change" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>

    <StackLayout Padding="10, 0" x:Name="SecondStack">
        <Label x:Name="secondLabel" Text="{Binding Path=SourceTwo.ExampleField}" FontSize="48" />
        <Label  Text="{Binding Path=SourceTwo.SourceTwoProp2}"  />
        <Button Text="Change" Clicked="Button_Clicked_1"/>
    </StackLayout>
    
</StackLayout>
```